# Change another div background when hover over another div

Tags: html, css

Trying to change a div background color when hover over another div. But I can't get it to worked. Been seing aroud her now, but can't find a similair question.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main {
        width: 960px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: red;
    }

    #trykk {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #trykk:hover #main {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<div id="main">
    <div id="trykk">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thats the code I've been using. The only problem is that I'm not allowed to use javascript. So is there any way I can change background color on div #main when I hover over div #trykk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A demo related to `Rodik's` answer, as he said you cannot change select parent using a child hence you cannot change the style of parent element, but if you want you can change your markup, as you said you cannot use javascript but if you can change the markup than it will go like this

[**Demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/sBk3M/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">Main</div>
<div id="trykk">Trykk</div>
```

CSS

```
#main:hover + #trykk {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Or if you want to nest your div's as you are doing right now, just change the selector like this

[**Demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/sBk3M/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">Main
<div id="trykk">Trykk</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main:hover > #trykk {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Those examples change the background colour of #trykk, however the question requests #main background changes colour

Comment: @DannyHearnah Did you just saw the examples or even read my answer? I already stated that in my answer

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. I just put both divs into a secton.

Comment: @user1770961 you welcome :) and if it helped you, you should mark answer as correct so that it will help future visitors too

Comment: how can I change #main background color when hovered over #trykk, keeping the hierarchy similar to demo 1. I tried this but that does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/sBk3M/92/

Answer (score 1):

CSS selection only works one way, from parent to child.

A child's state, hence, cannot affect it's parent's state.

A [javascript mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseover) event will be needed to implement this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you could do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#trykk").hover(function(){
        $("#main").toggleClass("greenBackground");
    });
});
```

Comment: **The only problem is that I'm not allowed to use javascript.** did you read this?